# How to calculate$ \sum \limits_{k=0}^{m-n} {m-k-1 \choose n-1} {k+n \choose n}$?

Tags: co.combinatorics, binomial-coefficients, combinatorial-identities

How to calculate $$\sum\limits_{k=0}^{m-n} {m-k-1 \choose n-1} {k+n \choose n}.$$

Comment: Mathematica finds $$\frac{\Gamma (m) \, _2F_1(n+1,n-m;1-m;1)}{\Gamma (n) \Gamma (m-n+1)} $$ for this sum.

Answer (score 10):

An easy combinatorial way to see that
$$\sum_{k=0}^{m-n}\binom{m-k-1}{n-1}\binom{k+n}n=\binom{m+n}{2n}:$$

The right hand side is the number of ways to pick a subset of size $2n$ from $\{1,2,\dots,m+n\}$.

The $k$ term on the left hand side is the number of ways to pick a subset of size $2n$ from $\{1,2,\dots,m+n\}$ whose $n$th element is $m-k$.

Comment: I cheated, of course, and reverse engineered the formula from T. Amdeberhan’s answer.

Comment: It's still a very nice combinatorial interpretation! @Jeremy Rickard

Answer (score 5):

This is the evaluation:
$$\sum_{k=0}^{m-n}\binom{m-k-1}{n-1}\binom{k+n}n=\binom{m+n}{2n}.$$
There might be a direct connection to Vandermonde's identity but let's apply the so-called Wilf-Zeilberger technique. To this end, divide through by the RHS and define the functions
$$F(m,k)=\frac{\binom{m-k-1}{n-1}\binom{k+n}n}{\binom{m+n}{2n}} \qquad \text{and}
\qquad 
G(m,k)=\frac{F(m,k)\cdot(m-n)!(m-k)k}{(-m+k+n-1)(m+n+1)}.$$
Then, check routinely that (for instance, divide through by $F(m,k)$ on both sides)
$$F(m+1,k)-F(m,k)=G(m,k+1)-G(m,k).$$
Now, sum both sides over all integers $k$ and notice that the RHS vanishes. That means $h(m+1)-h(m)=0$ where $h(m)=\sum_kF(m,k)$. It remains to check that $h(n)=1$ which implies $h(m)=1$ for all $m$. This completes the proof.

Comment: Thank you! Could you give me some hint how to simplify it? I guess there might be some relation with Vandermonde's Identity. But I cannot connect them clearly. @T. Amdeberhan

Answer (score 3):

Yes, it is Chu -- Vandermonde identity. We have ${m-k-1\choose n-1}={m-k-1\choose m-n-k}=(-1)^{m-n-k}{-n\choose m-n-k}$, ${k+n\choose n}={k+n\choose k}=(-1)^k{-n-1\choose k}$. Thus your sum equals
$$
(-1)^{m-n}\sum_{k=0}^{m-n} {-n\choose m-n-k}{-n-1\choose k}=
(-1)^{m-n}{-2n-1\choose m-n}={m+n\choose m-n}.
$$